# ExtJS 4 returning the records of a store when using a filterFn function

Tags: extjs

I have a simple `textfiled` that I use for searching in my grid by getting the inserted value and adding filter to the store like this:

```
instructionSearchField: function(field, e) {
        if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
            var searchTxt = this.getValue();

            this.recordsStore = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('Instructions');
            this.recordsStore.clearFilter(true);
            this.recordsStore.filter({
                filterFn: function(item) { 
                    return item.get('title').toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTxt.toLowerCase()) != -1;
                        }
                    });
            this.recordsStore.load();
            }
        },
```

And thus the user can serch as long as he wants - it works just as it has to. The problem is that at some point I want to return the state of the grid as it was before filtering/serching. Loading it from the server is not that easy so I wonder is there a way in ExtJS4 to return the begining state of a store, when local filter like the one above was used multiple times on it? The simple way for me would be to just return the basic state of the store adn then just load it, but I haven't found nothing like this in the documentation so - is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Leron

Comment: Is it remote filter? Or you just load all records into the memory first?

Comment: I'm working with ExtJS all the time.

Comment: No, I mean does your remote server do filtering? I don't think so. If this is the case you don't need to do load() after you apply filter, and to return everything to the original state - just call clearFilter() again

Comment: Yes, I get all the data from the DB, no filtering server side. But something new occurs. Do you know in filterFn: function() can I use more than one check?I mean - `return a > b; return c > d` does such kind of syntax legit?

Comment: Not sure I understand. You can out any logic you want into the fliterFn but it still need to return one value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use remote filtering (as in your server filters records and returns only matching set) you don't need to do `load()` after applying filters. Here is basic workflow:

- `store.load()` - after that your local copy has all records from the database
- `store.filter(...)` - you store still has all records in the memory but you have access to only ones that match your filter
- `store.clearFilter()` - you store again shows all records and you can apply different filter again (note that `load()` operation was performed only once)